# Axios calls with React : best practises

Tags: reactjs, redux

i want to know if there is some clean code or update to make it on my code, because i think i repeat the same code on every actions on my redux, my question is how can I avoid calling axios on my actions files ?

Please take a look on my code here :

```js
export const SignInType = (host, lang) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_SIGNINTYPE_REQUEST,
        });

        const { data } = await axios.get(
            `/${lang}/data?host=${host}`
        );
        console.log({ data });
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_SIGNINTYPE_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_CLEAR_ERROR,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_SIGNINTYPE_FAIL,
            payload: err,
        });
    }
};
```

I Really want to delete the Axios name from my actions file and make it on a separate file, but how can i do this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can suggest but there's no correct answer to this, initially any redundant lines of code can be abstracted, so in order to make things a little bit easier, we need to abstract the obvious and add the meaningful, e.g:

abstract the way you write action creators:

```js
const actionComposer = (options) => (...args) => async dispatch => {
  const modifiedDispatch = (type, payload) => dispatch({ type, payload });
  const { action, onSuccess, onFailed } = options(modifiedDispatch);
  try {
    if (action) {
      const res = await action(...args)
      onSuccess(res);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    onFailed(err)
  }
}
```

then your code can look like this:

```js
export const SignInType = actionComposer((dispatch)=> {
  return {
    action: async (host, lang) => {
      dispatch(USER_LOGIN_SIGNINTYPE_REQUEST);
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/${lang}/data?host=${host}`);
      return data;
    },
    onSuccess: (res) => {
      dispatch(USER_LOGIN_SIGNINTYPE_SUCCESS, data);
      dispatch(USER_LOGIN_CLEAR_ERROR);
    },
    onFailed: (err) => {
      dispatch(USER_LOGIN_CLEAR_ERROR, err.message)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux Toolkit already has [a `createAsyncThunk` API](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#fetching-data-with-createasyncthunk) that does all the work of defining the action types and dispatching them for you.  You should use that.

Alternately, you can use [our RTK Query data fetching and caching library](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics), which will eliminate the need to write *any* data fetching logic yourself.